# Angular2: how to pass child contents to directive?

Tags: angular

I have a custom directive which dynamically loads a component based on some input, so far that part works:

```html
<ng-container customDirective [variant]="something"></ng-container>
```

Using `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef`, I can then create the relevant component based on the value of `variant`. So far, this works.

But now I want the dynamic component(s) to include children like so:

```html
<ng-container customDirective [variant]="something">
  <span>I want to be inside the dynamic component!</span>
  <span>me too!</span>
</ng-container>
```

Simply using `<ng-content></ng-content>` inside the dynamic component template doesn't render the children.

It seems I need to pass the children to `createComponent`, something like this:

```js
const headerInstanceRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent<Component>(
  componentFactory,
  0,
  undefined,
  [
    // pass children here, somehow    
  ]
);
```

But I can't figure out how to retrieve them. I've tried using `ContentChildren` and `ViewChildren` in the directive, but both come up `undefined`.

The template where the directive will be used can contain multiple instances of that directive, each with its own separate set of children, so that's a concern as well.

Comment: I think you can still use <ng-content> but then your template also needs a second container that you can target as viewContainerRef in which you can create your component (you can set a local template reference on that container to target it with viewChild).. does that make sense?

Comment: @MikeOne not quite, sorry! my angular isn't that strong

Comment: I’m on mobile unfortunately so coding something up is a challenge. The question here is; do you need a container that has your dynamic component and next to it the content you pass in? Or do you need that passed in content inside your dynamic component?